# Overriding Views markup in handler file (views_handler_field.inc)

Tags: views, theming

I'm new to theming in Views, but I get the basic idea of working with templates. However, I want to make a small change to the `views_handler_field.inc` file without hacking Views. All I want to do is add an additional css class in order to open the read more link in a colorbox. This refers to the link that is output when trimming a field to a maximum length in the field settings.

What is the best way to do this? Is there some similar process for overriding handler files as there is for theme templates?

Comment: Can you precise which read more link?

Comment: Not the pager-based read more link but the one you find at "Trim this field to a maximum length" under "Rewrite results" in the field settings. I'm looking to add a class to ln 1179 of `views_handler_field.inc`: `$more_link = l($more_link_text, $more_link_path, array('attributes' => array('class' => array('views-more-link')))); `